# How to extract the word after pattern, but the word is in next line?

Tags: linux, bash

I want to extract every word that comes after the pattern, however, I can only extract the word is in the same line with the pattern, if the word is come right after a line break I'm not able to get it. For example,

```
Gary is a college student.
Steve and John are college
teachers.
```

I want to extract "student" and "teachers", but I only got "student" back.
My solution is

```
grep -oP '(?<=college )[\w+]*' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools like `grep` are fundamentally line oriented. GNU grep has a `-z` option to use 0 bytes as delimiters instead of newlines, though, which will let you treat the input file as a single big 'line':

```sh
$ grep -Pzo 'college\s+\K\w+' input.txt | tr '\0' '\n'
student
teachers
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep` (or really, generally, most Unix text processing tools) examine a single line, and can't straddle a match across line boundaries. A simple Awk script might work instead:

```
awk '{ for(i=1; i<NF; ++i)
    if ($i=="college") print $(i+1) }
$NF=="college" { n=1 }
n { print $1; n=0 }' file
```

You can easily refactor this to count the number of hits in Awk, too, and avoid the pipe to `sort | uniq` (or, better, `sort -u`), but I left that as an exercise. Learning enough Awk to write simple scripts like this yourself is time well spent.